# Meteor: Using @font-faces from MyFonts let Safari crash immediately

Tags: css, meteor, safari, crash, font-face

I added a family of @font-faces that I bought from myFonts to my Meteor project. As soon as I added them to the public folder and its definition to the stylesheet, Safari completely crashes. Used this font already in my Wordpress and Koken Themes without any problem.

The fonts come in several formats ttf, woff, woff2 and with a stylesheet that imports an URL for checking the license

`@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/xyz");`

With the xyz my counter id, which I think might be the problem. Didn't find anything on this so far. The fonts partially work in FF and Chrome. I need to use these fonts as a part of a corporate ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual reason for Safaris crashes is actually the Mac OS X (El Capitan 10.11.3) Screen Scaling function for retina displays on the Macbook pro (Retina, 15', Mid 2014, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M). It only crashes (and only with this one font) as soon as it is set to Maximum and works fine with the default resolution.